# Merge two dataframes by different indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on the `Date` column but in `df1` the data column is titled `Index` while the other is called `Date`.

#### `df1`

| Index | SMB | HML | RF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2019 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 2020 | 4 | 5 | 2 |

#### `df2`

| Date | ABC | DEF | GHI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 22 | 38 | 49 |
| 2019 | 41 | 42 | 59 |
| 2020 | 41 | 54 | 29 |

I have tried to set the index in DF1 but i keep getting the error message :
"None of ['Index'] are in the columns"

This is the code I have tried:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Index').T.set_index('Date').T
```

`df1` data was imported if that changes anything. I would like to eventually merge the two dataframes so it looks something like this:

#### `df3`

| Date | ABC | DEF | GHI | SMB | HML | RF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 22 | 38 | 49 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2019 | 41 | 42 | 59 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| 2020 | 41 | 54 | 29 | 4 | 5 | 2 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df3 = df2.merge(df1, right_on='Index', left_on='Date').drop('Index', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
   Date  ABC  DEF  GHI  SMB  HML  RF
0  2018   22   38   49    2    3   4
1  2019   41   42   59    4    4   5
2  2020   41   54   29    4    5   2
```

Comment: I tried this code and got another error message that just says: KeyError: 'Index'

Comment: Your dataframe(s) must not be exactly like your question says they are. Could you post the result of `print(df1.head().to_dict())` and `print(df2.head().to_dict())` to the question?

Comment: I cant post those results because my actual data numbers are much larger and they go over the character limit. Can you tell me what I should be looking for or another way to send the results?

Comment: You can upload a text file to something like https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/notHeff/20fd18a9b283e20ef1b4e7f3223b4a3e

Comment: Do your indexes have names? Try `print(three_yr_monthly_return.index.name)` and `print(three_yr_FF_French.index.name)`.

Comment: `three_yr_FF_French.index.name = "your_index_name"`

Comment: You'll need to do it for both dataframes first, and then change around `Index` and `Date` in my code samples to work.